# Flash ignores served policy file

Tags: flash, actionscript, cross-domain, policy

I'm working on a project in Flash and AS3 that requires sockets and I'm having trouble testing it in Debug mode (aka Ctrl+Shift+Enter mode). When connecting to the server, Flash issues a policy request

```
<policy-file-request/>
```

as expected, so my program serves a string that should act as a policy file:

```
elif "<policy-file-request/>" in data:
    return '<cross-domain-policy><allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="843"/></cross-domain-policy>'
```

And I can see in my output window that the string was sent successfully:

```
Sent <cross-domain-policy><allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="843"/></cross-domain-policy>
```

And yet, Flash continues to wait for the full 3 seconds, and when it's done, it complains about a "timeout on xmlsocket://127.0.0.1:843 (at 3 seconds) while waiting for socket policy file," and I get a Security Sandbox Violation. What's wrong with the policy file I sent?

Comment: It seems I was getting in a fuss over nothing. Adding a trailing \0 to the end of the policy file answer seems to have cleared up the problem. :)

Comment: i think this answers your problem
http://stackoverflow.com/a/14644759/260242